# How to run a linux program from matlab

Tags: linux, bash, matlab, sumo

I want to run a program from matlab command line. I use system command to run the traffic simulator, SUMO. Now the problem is sumo works fine on the bash shell but when I use

```
system('sumo -c ...');
```

It gives me the following error:

```
sumo: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by sumo)
sumo: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by sumo)
sumo: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFOX-1.6.so.0)
```

I shouldn't receive this error. I've even reset the PATH environment variable and appended all necessary system PATHs to it. But at the end it doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: looks like MATLAB runs system commands in a sandboxed terminal. You may have to mess around with your MATLAB installation files to fix this, which makes the solution very isolated to your own system...

Comment: Another way would be to find/build a version of `sumo` that works with the version of `libstdc++.so.6` that ships with MATLAB R2016b.

Comment: Does starting matlab from the command line as follows work: `LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6" matlab`?

Comment: The problem was addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40288599/matlab-system-does-not-run-applications